# Repeating values in a 2 dimensional array in objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm very new to objective c so I'm not sure if this is a simple or complicated question. I have been given a two dimensional array, each sub-array will only has two values. The first will be the value to repeat, the second will be the amount of times to repeat that value. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: To go about what? You haven’t explained what you are trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by `repeat that value`? Do you want to store those values in another array? Do you want to print them to the console, or display them on a label? Have you thought about learning Swift instead of ObjC?

Comment: If you need help with homework take a stab at producing something first then when you run into issues we will be happy to help. Start by creating a 2d array with values and then printing that out, then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the inner arrays at all. Make a class for it with two properties.

```
@interface Repetition
@property int value; // or whatever type
@property unsigned int count;
@end

@implementation Repitition
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!